# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'dispatcher.useState') WebView useState Error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, webview, simplemodal

TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'dispatcher.useState')

This error is located at:

in WebViewModal
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by Login)
in PortalProvider
in WebViewModalProvider (created by Login)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by Login)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by ScrollView)
in RCTScrollView (created by ScrollView)
in ScrollView (created by ScrollView)
in ScrollView
in Unknown (created by AnimatedComponent)
in AnimatedComponent
in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by NativeViewGestureHandler)
in NativeViewGestureHandler
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
in AnimatedComponent
in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by PanGestureHandler)
in PanGestureHandler
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by KeyboardAvoidingView)
in KeyboardAvoidingView (created by AnimatedComponent)
in AnimatedComponent
in AnimatedComponentWrapper
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by TapGestureHandler)
in TapGestureHandler
in RCTView (created by View)
in View
in ModalizeBase (created by Login)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by KeyboardAvoidingView)
in KeyboardAvoidingView (created by Login)
in Login (created by SceneView)
in StaticContainer
in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by CardContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by CardContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by CardContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View
in CardSheet (created by Card)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
in AnimatedComponent
in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by PanGestureHandler)
in PanGestureHandler (created by PanGestureHandler)
in PanGestureHandler (created by Card)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
in AnimatedComponent
in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by Card)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by Card)
in Card (created by CardContainer)
in CardContainer (created by CardStack)
in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
in AnimatedComponent
in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by InnerScreen)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)
in MaybeScreen (created by CardStack)
in RNSScreenContainer (created by ScreenContainer)
in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
in MaybeScreenContainer (created by CardStack)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by Background)
in Background (created by CardStack)
in CardStack (created by HeaderShownContext)
in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by StackView)
in RNGestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
in GestureHandlerRootView (created by StackView)
in StackView (created by StackNavigator)
in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
in NavigationContent
in Unknown (created by StackNavigator)
in StackNavigator (created by MainNavigator)
in MainNavigator (created by App)
in EnsureSingleNavigator
in BaseNavigationContainer
in ThemeProvider
in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
in App (created by withDevTools(App))
in withDevTools(App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in main(RootComponent)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import {
    Text, StyleSheet,
    KeyboardAvoidingView, ScrollView, Image,
    TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View, SafeAreaView,
    Linking, Modal
} from 'react-native';
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements';
import { Ionicons } from 'react-native-vector-icons'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Modalize } from 'react-native-modalize';
import WebViewModalProvider, { WebViewModal } from
    'react-native-webview-modal';


const Login = () => {
    const [input, setInput] = useState('');
    const [hidePass, setHidePass] = useState(true);
    const [ischecked1, setIschecked1] = useState(true);
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
    const modalizeRef = useRef(null);

    const navigation = useNavigation();

    function onOpen() {
        modalizeRef.current?.open();
    }

    return (

        <KeyboardAvoidingView
            style={styles.container}
        >
            **<Modalize
                ref={modalizeRef}
                snapPoint={500}
            //handlePosition="inside"
            >
                <View style={{
                    flex: 1, height: 500,
                    flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center'
                }}>
                    <WebViewModalProvider>
                        <View style={{ margin: 30, height: 500 }}>
                            <SafeAreaView />
                            <WebViewModal
                                visible={true}
                                source={{ uri: "https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/ChangePassword.aspx" }}
                                style={{ margin: 10 }}
                            />
                        </View>
                    </WebViewModalProvider>
                </View>
            </Modalize>**

            <ScrollView>

                <Image
                    source={require('../../assets/logo.png')}
                    style={styles.logo}
                />
                <Text style={styles.helloText}>
                    Olá de novo !
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.welcomeText}>
                    Bem-vindo(a) de volta,
                    sentimos sua falta!
                </Text>

                <TextInput
                    style={styles.inputArea}
                    placeholder="Digite o e-mail"
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.inputArea}
                    placeholder="Senha"
                    value={input}
                    onChangeText={(texto) => setInput(texto)}
                    secureTextEntry={hidePass}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.eye} onPress={() => setHidePass(!hidePass)}>
                    <Ionicons name={hidePass ? 'eye' : 'eye-off'}
                        color="#A0D800" size={25}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <View style={styles.checkBoxStyle}>
                    <CheckBox
                        left
                        size={18}
                        checkedColor='#A0D800'
                        value={ischecked1}
                        checked={ischecked1}
                        onPress={() => setIschecked1(!ischecked1)}

                        containerStyle={{
                            backgroundColor: "transparent",
                            borderColor: "transparent", marginRight: 0
                        }}
                    />
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setIschecked1(true)}>
                        <Text style={styles.Connected}>
                            Manter-se conectado
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity //onPress={() => 
                        // Linking.openURL('https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/ChangePassword.aspx')}
                        onPress={onOpen}>
                        <Text style={styles.forgotPassword}>
                            Esqueci minha senha
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.botao}
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate("TabNavigator")}
                >
                    <Text style={styles.botaoText}>Entrar</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>


            </ScrollView>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );

}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 2,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#fff'
    },
    logo: {
        marginTop: 50,
        marginBottom: 80,
        width: 150,
        height: 40,

    },
    inputArea: {
        marginTop: 30,
        padding: 15,
        height: 60,
        width: 370,
        borderColor: '#808080',
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        borderRadius: 15
    },
    botao: {
        width: 350,
        height: 60,
        backgroundColor: '#000000',
        marginTop: 35,
        marginLeft: 8,
        borderRadius: 15,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',

    },
    botaoText: {
        fontSize: 15,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: '#fff'
    },
    helloText: {
        fontSize: 40,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        marginTop: 15,
        color: '#000000',
        marginEnd: 120,
        marginTop: 8
    },
    welcomeText: {
        fontSize: 16,
        marginTop: 10,
        marginEnd: 35,
        marginVertical: 10,
        color: '#808080',
    },
    forgotPassword: {
        textDecorationLine: 'underline',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        marginTop: 15,
        marginBottom: 15,
        marginLeft: 30,
        fontSize: 12
    },
    Connected: {
        textDecorationLine: 'underline',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        marginTop: 15,
        fontSize: 12,
        marginRight: 55,
        marginLeft: -5
    },
    checkBoxStyle: {
        marginTop: 15,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        marginStart: -10
    },
    eye: {
        alignSelf: 'flex-end',
        bottom: 42,
        right: 40
    }
})

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0):

In using useState you set visible as false and also in your WebViewModal you set visible={true}.

This may be confusing. Maybe try changing the variable names in your useState definition say from

const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
to
const [isvisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

Not sure if that may be a solution but worth trying

Comment: Doesn't works :/ I don't know the problem